# JDBC ResultSet converting to an array like data type

Tags: java, jdbc, casting, resultset

I need to solve a java JDBC problem as follows:

```
 import com.interview.Check;

 class jdbcExample {

      public jdbcExample(){

           //Connection statements
      }

 public  Check[] getEligibleChecks(){

    Statement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    Check [] c;


        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from cc_table");

        while (myRs.next()) {

             //I need to store resultSet in Check[]

        }

    return c;


}
```

Here com.interview.Check has no source attached with it. How can I convert resultSet to one of Check data type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's JdbcTemplate, something like this

```
    JdbcTemplate t = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    BeanPropertyRowMapper<Check> rowMapper = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Check.class);
    List<Check> list = t.query("select * from cc_table", rowMapper);
```

Comment: I am allowed to use only core Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Check> list = new ArrayList<Check>();
while(myRs.next()){
    Check check = new Check();
    //Set the stuff you want into check object
    list.add(check); //Add it into list
}
```